# I updated my Jquery File Upload, and it started automatically submitting the form

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I have been using jquery file upload for a while and decided I wanted to use custom user folders. I upgraded to the latest version because there was custom folder functionality added. after upgrading the form would be submitted automatically every time I uploaded a file. I searched through the code to find an answer and on line 760 of jquery.fileupload.js I found this

```
            newData.submit = function () {
                newData.jqXHR = this.jqXHR =
                    (that._trigger('submit', e, this) !== false) &&
                    that._onSend(e, this);
                return this.jqXHR;
            };
```

I commented out this line

//(that._trigger('submit', e, this) !== false) &&

and now everything seems to work. I am not really sure if this was the right thing to do. but for now it works.

Comment: There is a support forum for jquery file upload.